package created in angular 14 and built with ng-packager does not have input and output suggestions
I've been trying for some time to make sure that my published package, once installed, suggests the input and output properties but I can't find the solution. Has anyone already faced this problem?
This is my public_api
export * from  './mfm-table/mfm-table.component'
export * from  './mfm-table/mfm-table.module'
export * from  './shared/models/action.model'
export * from  './shared/models/condition.model'
export * from  './shared/models/field-types.model'
export * from  './shared/models/filter.model'
export * from  './shared/models/function-table.model'
export * from  './shared/models/header-filter.model'
export * from  './shared/models/heder-config.model'
export * from  './shared/models/order-column.model'
export * from  './shared/models/table-order.model'

ng-packagr.json
{
 "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
 "dest": "./dist",
 "lib": {
 "entryFile": "src/lib/public_api.ts"
},
 "allowedNonPeerDependencies": [
  "@angular",
  "ng-packagr",
  "rxjs",
 "tslib",
  "zone.js",
  "@ngx-translate/core",
  "font-awesome",
  "pikaday",
  "moment"
 ]
 }

